# TextAlign and ImageAlign combinations in ImageBeforeText/TextBeforeImage relation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, alignment

Steps:

1. Add a CheckBox to the  Form.
2. Set **AutoSize** to **False** and set Size to (300,100).
3. Set **Image** property with an image.
4. Set **TextImageRelation** to **ImageBeforeText**.
5. Set **ImageAlign** to **MiddleLeft** and **TextAlign** to **MiddleRight**.

Output:

Both image and text are aligned to the left.

I am confused in the behavior of TextAlign and ImageAlign combinations when setting the **TextImageRelation** property to **ImageBeforeText** or **TextBeforeImage**. Can anyone please explain how these are implemented. I need to implement the same behavior in my custom CheckBox control.

Comment: Maybe you should choose TextImageRelation = Overlay to decouple text and image. also: are you talking about a real image or just the checkbox?

Comment: @TaW About the real image (bmp file of dimention 31X27) in the Image Property of CheckBox. I have edited the steps in the above thread. I couldn't understand the logic behind the alignments. How these are get aligned in the control when combined with TextImageRelation.

Comment: You are giving conflicting layout instructions.  You want the image before the text and on left, you got that, but also have the text at the far right.  You won't get that.

Comment: @Hans Passant Actually, I am creating my own CheckBox (say CheckBoxEx) control. I want these TextAlign and ImageAlign and TextImageRelation combinations in this control similar to .NET CheckBox control. The behavior of .NET CheckBox with these alignment combinations are very confusing. So any suggestion to implement these alignment combinations in my custom CheckBox control?

Answer (score 0):

TextImageRelation can tie text and image together.

You don't want that, so release them by setting TextImageRelation to 'Overlay'. Then the Alignments will work.